# Knockout enable binding not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I can't get the enable binding to work in Knockout JS. With the enabled property set to false, the button is not disabled and I can still click it.

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5CbnH/)

```
<a  class="btn btn-xl btn-primary" 
    href="#" 
    role="button" 
    data-bind="enable: enabled, click: clicked, visible: isVisible">
        <i class="icon-only icon-ok bigger-130"></i>
</a>      

var ViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    self.enabled = ko.observable(false);
    self.isVisible = ko.observable(true);
    self.clicked = function(){
        alert('You clicked the button');
    };
};

$(function(){
    var model = new ViewModel();
    ko.applyBindings(model);
})
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[Enable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/enable-binding.html) binding does not work with anything you want.

> This is useful with form elements like input, select, and textarea
>   It also works with buttons. Like in my example http://jsfiddle.net/5CbnH/1/

But it does not work with your link. You are using twitter bootstrap and they enable/disable their "buttons" with css classes. So you have to use [css binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) like this:

```
data-bind="css: { yourClass: enabled }"
```

Check what class is responsible in bootstrap for showing your "button" and modify your code accordingly with css binding.

Comment: Thanks. We came to the same conclusion but you got there faster.

Comment: This is old, but the fiddle needs a closing quote on the button's data-binding

Answer (score 26):

### Right:

**✅ enable
✅ disable**

### Wrong:

**❌ enabled
❌ disabled**

---

Make sure you use `disable` instead of `disabled` and `enable` instead of `enabled`.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: foo, enable: isEditing"/>   YES!!
<input type="text" data-bind="value: foo, enabled: isEditing"/>   NO!
```

Easy mistake to make :-)

Comment: I forget this at least once every 2 months.

Answer (score 11):

For people who might find this in a search:

I had a problem getting the enable binding to work as well.  My problem was trying to use a complex expression without referencing the observables like functions:

```
<input type="button" data-bind="enable:AreAllStepsVerified && IsFormEnabled, click:SubmitViewModel"/>
```

Should have been:

```
<input type="button" data-bind="enable:AreAllStepsVerified() && IsFormEnabled(), click:SubmitViewModel"/>
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15307588/4230970

Answer (score 6):

What Salvador said in his answer.

You must understand that the `enabled` and `disabled` binding in knockout work by putting a `disabled` attribute on the target DOM element. Now if you look at the HTML documentation you'd notice that not all HTML element support this attribute.

Actually only form elements (e.g. `<button>`) do. `<a>` does not.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by changing the anchor tag to a button, not really sure why this makes it work, but it works nonetheless.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5CbnH/2).

```
<button  class="btn btn-xl btn-primary" 
    role="button" 
    data-bind="enable: enabled, click: clicked, visible: isVisible">
        <i class="icon-only icon-ok bigger-130"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: This works because `a` does not have disable enable options. You either have to use bootstrap's css (as I suggested) or to make it a real button (like you changed here).